# Course Completion is stuck at pending status how ever the student passed all the activites and Quizzes in Moodle

Tags: php, block, moodle, completion

After creating a course and checking that all completion tracking settings are correctly modified in the Course settings and in the Activity settings. And after the student successfully passed the activities and quizzes, the Course Completion status is still pending and not completed. Even after adding self completion block, the same issue, the course is stuck at pending state only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Course completion is updated via the system [cron](https://docs.moodle.org/en/Cron) process.

Make sure your cron process is running or trigger it manually via [site]/admin/cron.php (if web running is enabled in your site settings) or on the commandline via:

```
php [site path]/admin/cli/cron.php
```

Comment: Thanks :)
sudo php  /path/to/moodle/admin/cli/cron.php >/dev/null
this one worked with me, after adding it to cron in the Debian.

Answer (score 0):

After creating a course and checking that all completion tracking settings are correctly modified in the Course settings and in the Activity settings. And after the student successfully passed the activities and quizzes, the Course Completion status is still pending and not completed. Even after adding self completion block, the same issue, the course is stuck at pending state only.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).